# Check ability to delete row from innodb;

Tags: mysql, innodb

I need to write query that will return true if i can delete row from innodb table, and false otherwise, or at least i whant query "DELETE FROM Table WHERE ID = 2" doesn't generate mysql error and just return affected rows = 0;

Comment: A SELECT instead the DELETE should give the information, if there is such an entry to delete. Please also specify the error returned by the specified query.

Comment: What is the bigger picture?  What will you do with the true/false return value?  Proceed to `DELETE` it?  `UPDATE` it if it is there?  Something else?  Perhaps you can completely fold this test into some other SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You must check if the row primary key is used in any table where it is defined as foreign key.

If tableXXX as a field table_id that is foreign key of table.ID field:

```
select count(table_id) from tableXXX where table_id = 2 limit 1;
```

And so on for every linked table.

Performing the delete inside a transaction, catching the error, and rolling back in case of error could also work but is a BAD idea.